# Animate to position not working

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/jX7An/3/

I've got the code that can be seen on jsfiddle above. I can't get it to animate for some reason. can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

-Edit- To expand, I'm looking to get something to duplicate and fly off the page (just trying to get it to 'fly' at the moment). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(this)
    .clone()
    .appendTo('body') // you must add the clone to the document
    .css({'position' : 'absolute', 'background-color' : '#F00'})
    .animate({opacity: 0.4}, 100 ).delay(100)
    .animate({opacity: 0.1, marginLeft: 100, marginTop: 500, width: 50, height: 50}, 100);
```

You've got to add the `clone()` element to the document.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jX7An/8/

Answer (score 1):

You aren't adding the clone to the body.

See http://jsfiddle.net/jX7An/10/.

Comment: Or actually use the clone and not just create it.

Comment: I'm looking to leave it there, but a copy to fly off the page. Any ideas how I can do this other than use clone?

Comment: @user1380591 Then append the cloned version to the DOM.

Comment: "Or actually use the clone and not just create it. – TheZ " - What do you mean by this? Thanks.

Comment: @user1380591. You are creating a clone of the element but not actually appending it to the page. The animation is taking place but the browser has not been told to render it.